# Regular expression to eliminate some data from string in java?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a string data which has some unwanted text. I want to delete that data from string using a regular expression. The example data is given below from which I want to eliminate the key `meth` and its corresponding data. The regular expression I created for this purpose is `"meth(S+)([\\},])"` but its not working.

I used the following code to use this regular expression:

```
json = json.replaceAll("meth(S+)([\\},])","");
```

**Below is the string data that is present in json :**

```
{
  data: [
    {
      "city": "barcelona",
      "Date": "4 Apr 2014",
      "Name": "A-B",
      "meth": function(){
        return_LANG=="en-us"?"A-T": "A-T "
      },
      "fo": "null",      
    },
    {
      "city": "Newyork",
      "Date": "4 Apr 2014",
      "Name": "B-C",
      "meth": function(){
        return_LANG=="en-us"?"S-E": "&#2358;&#2325;&#2381;&#2340;&#2367;&#2346;&#2369;&#2306;&#2332;&#2319;&#2325;&#2381;&#2360;."
      },
      "fo": "null",      
    }
  ]
}
```

The result I am getting is the same string as my regular expression is unable to find the matching data in String.

Please help me correcting my regex.

Comment: it should replace the value starting with "meth": till "}, with "".

Comment: not a valid json check with http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
json = json.replaceAll("(?s)meth.*?\\},", "");
```

Explanation:

- `(?s)` is for multiline regular expressions. The dot `.` will then also match new line characters (equal to the flag `DOTALL`, see [Pattern#DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL)).
- `.*?` searches any letter in a non greedy way till it finds the `},`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    s = s.replaceAll("(?s)\"meth\":.*?},\\s+","");
```

Comment: it's give me following exception :  java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 18: (?s)"meth":.*?},\s+